# C#: Exception handling with "using/try/catch" in WCF service

Tags: database, wcf, error-handling

I've just posted the question about general usage of "using/try/catch" construction and all is clear now.

But, I have a new question that is in connection with the previous one - how to use "using/try/catch" construction in case I have it in method in WCF service?  The goal is to see the description of particular database exception on client side.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, sqlServerFault, newEx.Action);
```

Take a look at this blog post [WCF error handling and some best practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've understood it. But, how can I propagate for example some database related exception to client level?

Comment: fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, sqlServerFault, newEx.Action);